# Are there are any examples of modern target/compilers where breaking strict aliasing in C affects the programs result?

Tags: c, strict-aliasing

Sometimes questions and answers on Stack overflow suggest pointer cast as a valid way of type punning. It is often refused by claims that this breaks strict aliasing and hence invokes undefined behavior.

Do modern targets really care about strict aliasing? Are there any instances of programs that would show unexpected behavior in this case?

Comment: asked 55 mins ago 
answered 54 mins ago

Comment: @cleblanc and the problem with that is?

Comment: Just [Google "`SIGBUS` SPARC"](https://www.google.com/search?q=SIGBUS+SPARC)  Probably more than half the links there are due to code that violates strict aliasing.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, strict aliasing is a *very real* phenomenon and is often leveraged by modern compilers to perform optimizations.

Consider the following code -

```
typedef struct
{
    char a;
} my_struct;

void foo( int * a, my_struct * b, int count )
{
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        a[i] += b->a;
    }
}
```

When compiled with `clang 3.8.0-2` (which is a very modern compiler) for the X64 target (which is also a very modern target) with the command -

```
clang -m64 -S -O2 -std=c11 foo.c -fno-vectorize -fno-unroll-loops
```

Produces the following assembly(simplified and in *AT&T* syntax) -

```
foo:
    testl   %edx, %edx
    jle     .LBB0_3
    movsbl  (%rsi), %eax   # Value loaded only once before start of loop
    .align  16, 0x90
.LBB0_2:
    addl    %eax, (%rdi)
    addq    $4, %rdi
    decl    %edx
    jne     .LBB0_2
.LBB0_3:
    retq
```

One can see that the value from `b->a` is loaded only once before the starting of the loop and added to all the integers in `a`.

But if this function is called as -

```
my_struct a[100];
// initializaion of values in a;
...

foo((int*)a, a, 2);  // Breaking strict aliasing
```

It is easy to see now how the result would be not what is expected.

On lower optimization levels **or** with `-fno-strict-aliasing` the compiler adds the instruction `movsbl (%rsi), %eax` inside the loop body.

Thus it is fair to conclude that modern architectures with modern compilers do leverage strict aliasing and hence pointer casts must not be used as a way of type punning.

**References**:
The example was motivated from this [blog post](https://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/articles/2006/06/understanding-strict-aliasing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Compilers like gcc and clang are either too primitive or too "clever" [or maybe both--depends upon who you ask] to recognize situations in which storage which has been used as one type needs to be accessed as another, even in cases that should be easily recognized by anything other than the most primitive compiler.  For example:

```
struct s1 { int x; };
struct s2 { int x; };
union s1s2 { struct s1 v1; struct s2 v2; };

int read_S1(struct s1 *p) { return p->x; }
void write_S2(struct s2 volatile *p, int v) { p->x = v; }

int test1(union s1s2 arr[], int i, int j)
{
    int temp;
    if (read_S1(&arr[i].v1))
    {
        temp = arr[i].v1.x;
        arr[i].v2.x = temp;
        write_S2(&arr[j].v2, 1);
        temp = arr[i].v2.x;
        arr[i].v1.x = temp;
    }
    return read_S1(&arr[i].v1);
}

int test2(union s1s2 arr[], int i, int j)
{
    int temp;
    { struct s1 *p = &arr[i].v1; temp = p->x; }
    if (temp)
        { struct s2 volatile *p = &arr[j].v2; p->x = 1; }
    { struct s1 *p = &arr[i].v1; temp = p->x; }
    return temp;
}
```

Neither clang nor gcc can properly handle the possibility that within `test1` or `test2`, `arr[i]` and `arr[j]` might identify the same storage even though there isn't actually any aliasing in the above code as written.  By any reasonable definition of aliasing, `arr[i]` and `arr[j]` don't alias if `i==j`--they simply apply the same index to the same array.  Further, all storage that is accessed using each pointer or any that is derived from it will be, within that pointer's lifetime, exclusively accessed that way, and thus none of the pointers alias anything either.

Unfortunately, both clang and gcc are too primitive to notice that between the lifetimes of the first and second pointers formed by taking the address of `arr[i].v1`, code had written to `arr[j]`, which could legitimately be the same lvalue as `arr[i]`.  Instead, they blindly assume that since the physical address of `arr[i].v1` will be the same both times, and since no operation that will actually change any bits of storage associated with that location do so using type `struct s1`, they're allowed to ignore everything else.

Answer (score -1):

> On lower optimization levels or with -fno-strict-aliasing the compiler
>   adds the instruction movsbl (%rsi), %eax inside the loop body.

It does not on lower optimizations levels.

your example is wrong as well as the function is constructed this way to invoke the UB as you have forgotten about the side effects of this punning. In this case - if you know that the value of the punned object can be changed by the program in the invisible to the compiler way you should use the volatile keyword. You have just made a typical volatile mistake.

This function is just vary badly written. Author knowing that it is prone to the side effects - has just ignored it. It is wrong with or without the pointer punning.

```
typedef struct
{
    char a;
} my_struct;

my_struct a, b[100];

void foo( int * a, my_struct * b, int count )
{
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        a[i] += b->a;
    }
}

void foo1( int * a, volatile my_struct * b, int count )
{
    int i;

    for (i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        a[i] += b->a;
    }
}


void call1(void)
{
    int *v = (int *)b;

    foo(v, &b[0], 100);
}

void call2(void)
{


    foo((int *)b, b, 100);
}

void call3(void)
{
    int *v = (int *)b;

    foo1(v, &b[0], 100);
}

void call4(void)
{


    foo1((int *)b, b, 100);
}
```

And the compiled code.

```
foo: # @foo
  test edx, edx
  jle .LBB0_3
  movsx eax, byte ptr [rsi]
  mov ecx, edx
.LBB0_2: # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
  add dword ptr [rdi], eax
  add rdi, 4
  add rcx, -1
  jne .LBB0_2
.LBB0_3:
  ret
foo1: # @foo1
  test edx, edx
  jle .LBB1_3
  mov eax, edx
.LBB1_2: # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
  movsx ecx, byte ptr [rsi]
  add dword ptr [rdi], ecx
  add rdi, 4
  add rax, -1
  jne .LBB1_2
.LBB1_3:
  ret
call1: # @call1
  mov rax, -400
  movsx ecx, byte ptr [rip + b]
.LBB2_1: # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
  add dword ptr [rax + b+400], ecx
  add rax, 4
  jne .LBB2_1
  ret
call2: # @call2
  mov rax, -400
  movsx ecx, byte ptr [rip + b]
.LBB3_1: # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
  add dword ptr [rax + b+400], ecx
  add rax, 4
  jne .LBB3_1
  ret
call3: # @call3
  mov rax, -400
.LBB4_1: # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
  movsx ecx, byte ptr [rip + b]
  add dword ptr [rax + b+400], ecx
  add rax, 4
  jne .LBB4_1
  ret
call4: # @call4
  mov rax, -400
.LBB5_1: # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
  movsx ecx, byte ptr [rip + b]
  add dword ptr [rax + b+400], ecx
  add rax, 4
  jne .LBB5_1
  ret
```

Comment: In your example, the `volatile` is in wrong place. There is no reason for `my_struct *b` to be `volatile`. That is not the instance where punning his happening. Punning is happening on `int*`. Try making that volatile and you will still see that the compiler optimizes the load.

Comment: *if you know that the value of the punned object can be changed by the  program in the invisible to the compiler* -- no it is not invisible. It is happening right inside the loop. When writing to `a[i]`

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya it is in the correct place- as it has to be in this badly written example.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya Punning hides it. Programmer has to aware of it. If he is not aware - probably will have same problems without the punning

Comment: You can't add `volatile` to __every__ pointer because somewhere it is being accessed with a different type. Also the fact that adding `-fno-strict-aliasing` inserts a load proves that it is not a `volatile` issue but a aliasing issue.

Comment: *Punning hides it. Programmer has to aware of it. If he is not aware - probably will have same problems without the punning* -- that is EXACTLY what strict-aliasing is. The compiler can assume that two pointers of different types do not alias. You should read the standards.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya this is the demagogy. I discuss your example. Pointer punning should not be used in similar circumstances.

Comment: Let me correct you there, *pointer punning should never be used*.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I agree - should never be used by the programmers who do not understand the consequences of its use.

Comment: I don't want to participate in any useless name calling. I have made my point.

Comment: *It does not on lower optimizations levels.* -- yes `clang` does it at `-O0`.

Comment: `-O0` is not lower optimisation level. It means no optimizations. In this case any variable will be always read or pointer dereferenced before use. Aliasing does not have anything in common with it : https://godbolt.org/g/6HRgU8 . If you advice studying - please study yourself before commenting

Comment: "_pointer punning should never be used_" Can you backup that claim?

Comment: On a compiler had quality `volatile` semantics, using `volatile` on a type-punned pointer might coax sensible behavior from a compiler that is otherwise too primitive to recognize that code which takes the address of a union member and immediately uses it might actually be accessing the union (and thus observe or affect the other members).  On gcc or clang, however, even adding a volatile qualifier to the type-punned pointer won't prevent nonsensical "optimizations".